# Convert string to color VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, colors

I am Using colordialog to let user pick a color, which is then saved into a db. when loading the color to fill a lable it comes as a string. 
How to convert:

```
Color `[A=255, R=128, G=128, B=255]` to color
```

Is there a way to save user selected values

If I use these options, the alpha value will be lost

```
Dim c As Color
c = Color.FromName("red")
c = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0)  
c = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Red)
```

Comment: Color. FromArgb()  has an overload expecting 4 values where the first one is the alpha channel value

Comment: Is it necessary to store the data as text?  If you were to store it as a 32-bit integer then you can simply use `Color.ToArgb` and `Color.FromArgb`.

Comment: Do you create that string?  It is almost looks like the format a serializer might come up with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments say you can store the `32-bit ARGB value`. It's basically a numeric value. If you code this way then there won't be any need to write a function to extract the color value.

```
'your string selected from a color dialog
Dim clrDialog As New ColorDialog
If clrDialog.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        TextBox1.Text = clrDialog.Color.ToArgb.ToString 
End If
clrDialog.Dispose()

' to get back ARGB value from string
TextBox1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(CInt(TextBox1.Text))
```